# Can Cytoscape calculate centrality?

Tags: statistics, cytoscape, sna

does somebody know whether Cytoscape can calculate statistical numbers like centrality (degree, betweenness centrality, closeness centrality), denity and clique analysis?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Cytoscape includes the ability to calculate several of the centrality measures, as well as other network metrics.  There are also apps (see, for example, centiscape) that go even further.  For the built-in tool, look at Tools->Analyze Network.

-- scooter